# Is it possible to log request results in httperf?

Tags: performance, load-testing, httperf

I'm using [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) for load testing. I have two HTTP endpoints to be tested. 
However, the second endpoint needs the result of the first one. That is, requests to the second endpoint need to pass a parameter which is generated by the first endpoint.

So, I have to log the response of the first endpoint. Then I will generate the request URI for my second call using this log.

Is it possible to log the results of the tested requests in httperf? If not, can you recommend me an alternative way or testing tool?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible with httperf, have a look to Tsung https://tsung.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ or Gatling http://gatling.io/ eventualy JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/ all these third tools have this beehaviour.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option  `[−−print−reply [header|body]]` 
Check manpage for more details.